# My python webscraper using selenium doesn't work everytime. What is wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

So I was just experimenting with webscrapers and I got a basic piece of code that just opens a webpage using selenium and the chrome drivers. However I have had this issue since I started where it won't work everytime. Sometimes the webpage will load up to the amazon home page. The other times it will look like this: [image: Example]

I found that changing the link by taking away the slash and removing the 's' from 'https' would make it work almost every other time. This is my code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    url = "http://amazon.com/"
    PATH = r"C:\Users\tyler\chromedriver.exe"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    browser.get(url)
```

Please help if you can. I have friends who are doing the same thing and having no problems at all.
Thank you.

**EDIT**
There are instances of chromedriver.exe left running on working attempts. Not sure if that'd affect anything.

Comment: what operating system are you running? could be due to proxies.

Comment: @Insula I am using Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Okay do your friends have the same script and operating system as you? Of course the directories are going to be different, but other than that are there any other differences in the script?

Comment: @Insula My friends have the same operating systems. They test ran the same script and had consistent results unlike myself.

Comment: okay so it is something to do with selenium. try uninstalling and reinstalling selenium, the chrome webdriver too. You should also check if your Chrome is up to date, type about://chrome in the search bar and find the version, then install the correct driver for it.

Comment: @Insula So I got rid of all of Selenium and reinstalled it. I also deleted all traces of the chrome webdriver from my PC and reinstalled that. My chrome is version 88.0.4324.146, so that corresponds with my webdriver version. In the end, nothing changed :/.

Comment: that's weird.. double check the path locations, other than that i don't think i can help mate

Comment: thanks for trying, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is on your connectivity. The mere fact selenium is able to open a web browser means it is working

Comment: I guess that could be an issue. Thanks for the input.